# Уникальный процесс в одноранговой сети?

Tags: c#, .net, service, lan, p2p

Есть процесс(сервис), он должен быть один в одноранговой сети. То бишь, только на одной машине должен быть запущен этот процесс. Есть ли какие-то инструменты в PowerShell или в c# для обеспечения уникальности процесса в одноранговой сети.

Comment: Вообще-то это забота самого сервиса - определять факт наличия конкурента и не стартовать, а если запустился - мониторить появление конкурентов и гонять их.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужен 1 instace  можно и через мутекс

```
bool singleApp;

Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "ServiceName", out singleApp);
//ето как Lock но на уровне процессов может работатъ

if (!singleApp)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Я так понял это инстанс для одной машины?